# How use GridView in Notification

Tags: android, gridview, notifications

**Hello!** Can I use the GridView in Custom Notifications? Where can I read about it? Tutorial or manual? Or... how to make the switch in the notifications and dynamically with scrolls? I searched and could not find anywhere information about my questions. Sorry for my english. Thank you!!! :)

Comment: In theory, you could use `GridView`, attempting to follow [the instructions for how you use `GridView` with an app widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections). That being said, I have never tried this and would not be surprised if there are issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GridView` is one of the supported widgets in `RemoteView` as is `GridLayout`.

You can use it just you would if you were to create a simple custom notification. take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-custom-notification-tutorial/). and take a look at [App.Widgets Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) for a list of supported widgets.

One more thing to keep in mind is that content inside of a notification is not scrollable, so keep that in mind when you add content to your grid